# Python recursive function to return the mean of the digits in a number

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that returns the average of the digits in a number. For example the average of the number 123 is 2. I know how to write a function that sums the digits but without using for I am no able to return the number to divide the function.
The print value cannot be change so i can't pass a number of digits or something like that.

```
def media(x):
  if x<1:
    return 0
  else:
    return x%10+media(x//10)

print(media(91234))
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for`?

Comment: You could use two functions. One that only sums the digits and one that does the final division.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a `for`-loop

There is really no reason not to use a `for`-loop for this.

```py
def media(x):
  if x == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    digits = []
    while x > 0:
      digits.append(x % 10)
      x = x // 10
    return sum(digits) / len(digits)
```

### If you insist on recursion

You can use additional accumulator parameters to store the sum of digits and the number of digits:

```py
def media(x, sumSoFar=0, nDigitsSoFar=0):
  if x == 0 and sumSoFar==0:
    return 0
  elif x == 0:
    return sumSoFar / nDigitsSoFar
  else:
    return media(x // 10, sumSoFar + (x % 10), nDigitsSoFar + 1)
```

Please note that python is one of the worst languages for recursion, and in particular it doesn't optimize tail-calls.

### Cheating: letting python handle the conversion to string

The builtin function `str` will convert an integer to a string of digits. You can use this in conjunction with `ord` to get the value of a digit:

```py
def media(x):
  s = str(x)
  return sum((ord(c) - ord('0')) for c in s) / len(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is the **mean** and not the **median** as it seems like you've written. To find the mean of the digits, you can convert the number into a type `str` then extract each digit by iterating over the string with a `for ... in string`. Next, convert each digit back and find the average of those numbers.

EDIT: It's not recursive, but it doesn't seem meaningful to use recursion for this kind of simple calculation.

Comment: Yes that is the issue with the for I can do it but only with a recursive approach I was not able to.